# How to pass @formparam in post method of URI via mozilla restclient

Tags: java, web-services, rest, rest-client

I have created a restful webservice in java, while testing it on mozilla restclient I am unable to pass @formparam. Can someone please help me to do the same.
Please find the code of my webservice below:

```
@Path("/user/service")
public class UserServices {
    @GET
    public String getFunc(@FormParam("username") String username) {
        System.out.println("getFunc");
        return username;
    }
    @POST
    public String postFunc(@FormParam("username") String username) {
        System.out.println("postFunc");
        System.out.println("username is " + username);
        return username;
    }
}
```

Here is a screenshot how I am passing @formparam to the mozilla restClient:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdGrk.png)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing the `POST` method to accept a `Map` (i.e. request body), e.g.:

```
@POST
public String postFunc(final MultivaluedMap<String, String> formParams) {
    System.out.println(formParams);
}
```

You can then `print` the content of the `Map` and see which parameters are retrieved on the server side.